# Flutter - This function has a return type of 'FutureOr<XXX>', but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want return a future with a value from a try catch block:

```
  Future<UserCredential> createUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        Get.snackbar(
            'Error Creating Account', 'The password provided is too weak.',
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        Get.snackbar('Error Creating Account',
            'The account already exists for that email.',
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      Get.snackbar('Error Creating Account', e.message as String,
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    }
  }
```

But it gives this error:

> This function has a return type of 'FutureOr<UserCredential>', but
> doesn't end with a return statement. Try adding a return statement, or
> changing the return type to 'void'.

Can I make this return a future that has a value in it and also handles the error in the function or do I have to change the return type to `Future<void>`?

Comment: What do you want the function to return to the caller when an exception is thrown?  If you want the caller to get a null `UserCredential` on failure, add `return null` to the end of your `catch` block.

Comment: @jamesdlin oh that's interesting, it seems to let me return null even when I put the return type Future<UserCredential> in the signature.

Comment: If you don't have the new null safety features enabled, why wouldn't it?  Without null-safety, a `UserCredential` can be null. (With null-safety, the return type would need to be `Future<UserCredential?>`.)

Comment: @jamesdlin It just surprised me as in Typescript you can't return null when you have specified another return type. You can specify <T | null> if you want to do that. I tried to get null safety features enabled a couple of days ago, but I keep seeing Github issues saying it is not possible yet, and the dart IntelliSense suggesting you can enable it if you upgrade to dart version 2.10.0 or higher is incorrect, which is also what I have experienced firsthand. If you have got it working I am interested to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return value has to be of the type declared with the Future's generic type.  If there are any code paths that don't return a UserCredential, then you can't use this declaration.  If you have no return value, then yes, it should be `Future<void>`.  But it seems that you do have a return value in at least one code path.

Consider instead moving all of the UI code out of this method and simply let the function throw whatever it throws (or re-throw something else).  Then, make the caller of this function catch the error and decide what to show in the UI for that case.